# domain doesn't set cookie for the subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

I have a domain "www.example.com" and i have tried to set the cookie "CSjrkIU" only for the subdomain "www.status.example.com"

My code is :

```
setcookie("CSjrkU", ed717822dd2e3aUsvoRye0668d, time()+60*60*24*365*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/", "www.status.example.com");
```

My problem is the browser didn't set this cookie by the domain for the subdomain..i don't know why

Also how i can let the domain "www.example.com" read that cookie ?

I have tried many of things but it doesn't work :(

Could anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 4):

Try to set it this way for subdomain:

```
setcookie("...", ed..., ti..., "/", ".example.com");
```

starting with `.example.com`

Comment: I need to set this cookie "CSjrkIU" only for just the subdomain "www.status.example.com" by the "www.example.com"

Comment: @Maroman you cant like that, the only work around i can think of is to maybe add an iframe to the page with 'www.status.example.com' domain, or you can redirect to that subdomain, set the cookie and redirect back to www.example.com

Comment: Thank you Ibu. that is good ideas. does let the domain "www.example.com" read that cookie ?

Answer (score 2):

"www.status.example.com" *is not* a subdomain of "www.example.com". Thats the reason why your cookie is rejected. You *can not* change this behaviour, thats a security policy in the browsers.

Change your code to use a proper subdomain like "status.www.example.com" for example.

Comment: do you have other solution can help please ?